# RubyMine to ignore some files when going to file

Tags: rubymine

When going to file (Go To => File, ⇧⌘N on Mac OS X), is there a way to have RubyMine ignore some directories? We have a lot of third party code in vendor which I'd rather ignore.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**File | Settings | Project Structure**, select directory on the right and press **Excluded** button on top:

[image: Exclude Directories]

Comment: Slight hitch with this solution; excluded folders are no longer indexed by RM. The ideal scenario is if I wish to exclude my vendor/gems folder only for searching(as I rarely search it).

Comment: In v5.4, you can right click the folder and choose 'Mark Directory As | Excluded'. This won't force the current indexing to stop. You have to select 'File | Invalidate Caches...' to finally get it to stop.

Answer (score 2):

The quicker way:

Right-click on a folder in your project tree and click `“Mark Directory As” → “Excluded”`.

[image: directory-exclude-screen-shot]